# Error indexing Alpha pages

Tags: page-numbering, indexing

I am trying to make a sort of recipe book for myself.
I would like to have every recipe a "page reference" given by a letter representing the category (main courses, dessert, biscuits, ...) and a progressive neverchanging number, so that I can add recipes and I do not 
have to print them again.
Anyway, I redefine the page counter (?) and everything seems fine but when I index some entries, the index result wrong, as you can see from this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tabularx,imakeidx,siunitx}

\newcounter{recipe}
\setcounter{recipe}{0}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\Alph{section}\arabic{recipe}}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{
    \newpage
    \setcounter{recipe}{0}
    \section{#1}
}
\newcommand{\recipe}[1]{
    \newpage
    \stepcounter{recipe}
    \subsection{#1}
}
\newcommand{\Index}[1]{
    #1
    \index{#1}
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mysection{Antipasti}
\recipe{insalata russa}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\recipe{crostini toscani}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\mysection{Primi}
\recipe{gnocchetti primavera}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\recipe{lasagne}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\recipe{bucatini all'amatriciana}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\printindex

\end{document}
```

index should report both "farina" and "zucchero" in each and every page (A1, A2, B1, B2, B3), instead you'll find a funny

farina, A1, B1; zucchero, A2, B2

Please note that this is a very very simplified example and that there are good reason to make it this way, so do not try to just suggest a different method (though a different latex way to do it would be obviously fine).

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you are asking. I you have 'good reason to make it this way' and don't want anybody to 'suggest a different method', what do you want? You say 'a different latex way' would be fine but then what do you mean by 'a different method'? What can be changed and what can't? I have no idea... I don't know if this is part of the method you can't change but redefining `\thepage` is not going to do what you want as it does not touch the page counter which I'd guess is what the index uses. It outputs the value of the counter but it is not the counter itself.

Comment: @cfr sorry, I meant I need the page numbering to be as explained, I cannot accept suggestion like "it is useless: make the page number like 3A instead of A3" or "use C2 for page numbering and the corresponding 47 for indexing"

I suppose index is not expected to do what is doing in this example (it is not reporting all the indexed pages), so either I made some mistake or there's some problem somewhere and I have to find a way around. In either case I need a suggestion from someone with much more deep knowledge than mine. Hope this explain my question

Comment: Does it really need to define the page number as 'A3' or whatever? The problem is that the page number is a *counter* but that is not one. (What comes after A3? A4 or B1?) You might be able to achieve a similar effect by defining *two* counters: one for section and one for recipe or whatever. So 'A' would be one and '3' the other. Then you would adjust your page layout to print these *rather than* the page number, and possibly you could fix things so these were also printed in the index *rather than* the page number. But I don't see any easy way to define the page number as you wish.

Comment: @cfr Yes I do :) (let's say editor mandatory requirement, ok?) 

I honestly do not see the problem: you ask "What comes after A3? A4 or B1?", to me sound like "what comes after 13? 14 or 21?" and the answer seems pretty obvious. Anyway, thsi may be a good way around: two counters (no problem) change the page layout to show both counters concatenated (I suppose I can do it), but I do I get A3 or B1 in the index? that is crucial

Comment: Equally obviously I must be too dense to appreciate the pattern because it certainly is far from obvious to me what the answer is. Unless you mean it is obvious because there is no A3 in your example so nothing follows. But then what follows B3? B4 or C1? If it is required by an editor, ask if they have a customised class, package or template - no point in reinventing the wheel. They should have if they are requiring you to use this kind of bizarre numbering. If they don't know how to do it either, perhaps they should rethink their requirements!

Comment: @cfr ok, maybe I'm too much into computer world (and unpolite), so you won the whole story (I just tried to be concise). First, perhaps I got your answer wrong, I meant "what is the ordered sequence of A3, A4, B1?" and the answer (think them as hexadecimal number) IS obvious; you probably meant "what number is the successor of A3?" and the answer is NOT obvious. Now the reason: my granny's mom started to write some recipe annotation on pieces of paper kept together by a string, then my granny added some recipes and numbered them all guess how? Yes: A1, A2, ..., B1, B2 and so on. (2b continued)

Comment: My mom kept on with the tradition and now everybody in the family says stuff like "why don't you make a C22 for Xmas?" or "I'd like a D40 for my bDay". Now they're all dead and during last Christmas eve the youngsters told me they would like to have a (better digital) copy of the recipe book. I will do it in a way or another; I could have done with Xpress but I would like to share the source files, having them under version control, to share the whole family annotations on each recipe and I believe in Tex power, so I tried this way. Maybe I'm a romantic geek.So how can I get the index "right"?

Comment: That sounds doable because it doesn't sound as if you need the 'real' page number to be A3 or whatever. It will be fine for TeX to think it is page 27 so long as it prints 'A3' and you can somehow get that into the index. I don't know much about creation of indices but I think that's a lot more likely to be possible than trying to actually have the page numbers be A3 etc. as the page number pretty much has to be a counter and counters are the kind of thing which can be incremented, and that requires the successor of any member of the sequence to be 'obvious' (and obvious to *TeX*).

Comment: I don't think anyone's mentioned so far what the cause of the problem is. It's due to the fact that `makeindex` requires a compositor between different number formats. So, for example, if you had `A-1`, `A-2` etc, `makeindex` would work fine. However it won't accept an empty compositor, which is what `A1` essentially has. With this numbering style you're restricted to `xindy` as per @cfr's answer.

Comment: @Nicola: where did you get the info needed for this answer? I read makeindex documentation (and imakeidx, and some other) but I did not find anything about that. Maybe I should have read all the Tex code and deduct form there?

Comment: The page compositor bit is set in the `makeindex` style. I found the information in the [Linux man page for makeindex](http://linux.die.net/man/1/makeindex) while I was working on my `glossaries` package which uses the same mechanism when in `makeindex` mode but it should also be in http://mirror.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/paper/ind.pdf.

Comment: I found the same information as Nicola in the `xindy` manual. This isn't what you get if you say `texdoc xindy` but you can find it in `doc/xindy/manual.html`. However, I dismissed this as you were adamant that the page numbers had to be exactly as you'd stipulated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Traditionally organised recipes digitised for the younger generation]

Perhaps this will give you a start. I'm not sure what you plan to do about page numbering before and after the recipes so I expect that will need to be adjusted.

This requires two runs of `pdflatex` with a run of `texindy` in between to create the index. This is because I don't know how to adjust the references using `makeindex`. `xindy` seems more flexible. (But note that I don't use indexing much so I'm certainly not claiming this is the only way. Just this is what I found after reading a bunch of bits and pieces.)

You need an additional module for `texindy` which defines a special sort of `location` for recipes. Put these lines in a file with `.xdy` extension. I used `recipes.xdy`.

```
cat recipes.xdy
 (define-location-class "recipes" :var
    ("ALPHA"
     "arabic-numbers"))
```

This file cannot be created using the `filecontents` package as `texindy` doesn't like the comment lines which are inserted at the top. You therefore need to make this by hand. But it is only 3 lines of code so hopefully that shouldn't be too problematic. Either keep it in the same directory as your document or install it somewhere `xindy` will find it.

I use a command from `imakeidx` to write the relevant location information to the `.idx` file. This is wrapped in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` as it is really intended for package authors, it seems.

If your recipes are in `myrecipes.tex`, to compile, run:

```
pdflatex myrecipes.tex
texindy -M recipes myrecipes.idx
pdflatex myrecipes.tex
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
% put the following lines in recipes.xdy
%   (define-location-class "recipes" :var
%      ("ALPHA"
%       "arabic-numbers"))
% after processing with pdflatex, run texindy -M recipes <jobname>.idx
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\recipenumbering}{%
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\Alph{section}\arabic{recipe}}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0em}
  \fancyhf[cf]{\Alph{section}\arabic{recipe}}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0em}
    \fancyhf[cf]{\Alph{section}\arabic{recipe}}}}
\newcommand{\prerecipenumbering}{%
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0em}
  \fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0em}
    \fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}}}
\newcommand{\postrecipenumbering}{%
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0em}
  \fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0em}
    \fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}}}

\newcounter{recipe}
\setcounter{recipe}{0}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
    \newpage
    \setcounter{recipe}{0}
     \section{#1}}
\newcommand{\recipe}[1]{%
    \newpage
    \stepcounter{recipe}
    \subsection{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Index}[1]{%
    #1
   \imki@wrindexentry{\jobname}{#1}{\Alph{section}\arabic{recipe}}}
\makeatother

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\prerecipenumbering
\tableofcontents

\clearpage\recipenumbering

\mysection{Antipasti}
\recipe{insalata russa}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\recipe{crostini toscani}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\mysection{Primi}
\recipe{gnocchetti primavera}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\recipe{lasagne}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\recipe{bucatini all'amatriciana}
\Index{farina}\\
\Index{zucchero}\\
\blindtext

\clearpage\postrecipenumbering
\printindex

\end{document}
```

I hope all members of the younger generation appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Wow! I surely appreciate YOUR effort :) Thanks a lot for such a lot of work to solve my problem. I tried it and it works even if (please don't be offended) I suppose I'll adopt the solution suggested by NicolaTalbot, being much simpler to my code. As for youngster, you know: they're youngster as we were some years ago :) They'll begin appreciating in some years ...

Comment: @massi See my comment above! This was actually interesting and I learnt something about how `xindy` works. (Not a whole lot but enough to give me an idea.)